# Cross Domain error in IE 8

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I use DotNetNuke( ASP.NET ) Web API and use cross domain requests. It works fine in all browsers( IE9+,Chrome,Mozilla ) except IE8. Also requirements is to use POST( not GET ) method.

My Code:

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
    $('#divPanel').hide();
    jQuery('#btnGet').click( function(){
                $.ajax({
                url: "https://www.someurl/Controller/Action",
                crossDomain: true,
                data: { '': $('#txt').val() },
                type: "POST",
                xhrFields: {withCredentials: false  },
                dataType: "json"
            }) .done(function( msg ) {

                })
                 .fail(function(error) {
                        alert( "Some error occured." );
                }); 
    } );    
} );
```

Cross domain request doesn't work, i got error: 'No Transport' in IE8
Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Define doesn't work? (PS, your rep is very evil)

Comment: Cross domain request doesn't work, i got error: 'No Transport' in IE8

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax "No Transport" error in IE 8 & 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309037/ajax-no-transport-error-in-ie-8-9)

Comment: try this: http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/

Comment: @Dalorzo json3.js won't solve any issues with cross-origin requests

Comment: @RayNicholus the issue suggests that it is browser specific.

Comment: @Dalorzo My guess is that it is not related to support of the `JSON` object, since IE8 doesn't lack support for this (IE7 does).  Therefore, a polyfill isn't likely to solve the issue.  I suspect the same issue exists in IE9 for the OP, and the error message suggests that the transport is the issue, not lack of JSON support.

Comment: Another thing may be <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /> or the recommended by Microsoft <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="edge" />